# Python saving data to file/global variable in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, file, loops, dataframe

I have two for loops in which I call the forecast function. The function returns the forecast value and I want to write it to a file or in a dataframe such that I can save all the predictions and access them outside the loop scope. I am a little stuck here. let me show by example.

```
 for country in df['country'].unique():
      for channel in df['channel'].unique():
          output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'country', 
                                          'channel_id','value'])
          x = df[df['country']==country & df['channel']==channel]
          pred = forecast(df)
          output = output.append(pred)
          output.to_csv('forecast.csv')
```

This is what I want to do but the problem is, well obvious, the data is lost after each iteration. Please suggest a way to keep it.

Comment: Just pull `output.to_csv('forecast.csv')` out of the `for` loops. However, even though the file continually gets overwritten, you will be sequentially adding more data on each write so the data should eventually all be there

Comment: I tried that. It was an empty file. Apparently because if I take it out, it goes out of scope. Not sure really

Comment: It cannot go out of scope from what you've shown. However, we also can't see how you initialise `output`

Comment: just edited and added the output initialization, would it work if I initialize output before the loops? @roganjosh

Comment: Oh, well now the issue is clear. You need to pull `output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'country', 'channel_id','value'])` out of both `for` loops; you keep trampling over the df and resetting it on each iteration. Define before the loops.

Comment: Loops do not create a scope.

Answer (score -1):

To delimit by a tab you can use the sep argument of to_csv:

> output.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')

To use a specific encoding (e.g. 'utf-8') use the encoding argument:

> output.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Where was there any mention of delimiters? The OP says they are losing the data, not that they don't know how to specify the delimiter.